# C#, ASP.NET how to call method during each call of any method of my Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How I can call method, for example **checkouth()** eveytime when user enter on Controller's page
For example I have a few `ActionResults` - Create,Edit,Details,Orders and Index. Is it possible to call my method (**checkouth()**) before calling of methods from Contoller? It is required to check user access and redirect to another page.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your action filter for that

```
public class CheckouthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
         new RouteValueDictionary{{"controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Error" }});
    }
}

[Checkouth]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Update:**
Now It will redirect to `Error` Action. Return view also possible:

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Error",
            ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData
        };
    }
```

Comment: is it required to put [Checkouth] before each ActionResult method ?

Comment: interface member is not implemented - this error appear when I insert public class CheckouthAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter. Could you help please ?

Comment: and is it possible to return View from my method, I want to return error page for example ?